# Many Fields In the Group By Clause

Tags: sql

I am learning SQL now, and I have a question.  I recently came across a query that hand a large number of column names in the group by clause.  I've used group by clauses before, and I've only ever seen one column name included in it.

```
SELECT        TransportType.Description, TransportType.CargoCapacity, TransportType.Range, Transport.SerialNumber, Transport.PurchaseDate, Transport.RetiredDate, 
                         MAX(Repair.BeginWorkDate) AS LatestRepairDate

FROM            Transport INNER JOIN
                         TransportType ON Transport.TransportTypeID = TransportType.TransportTypeID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         Repair ON Transport.TransportNumber = Repair.TransportNumber

GROUP BY TransportType.Description, TransportType.CargoCapacity, TransportType.Range, Transport.SerialNumber, Transport.PurchaseDate, 
                         Transport.RetiredDate

HAVING        (Transport.RetiredDate IS NULL)

ORDER BY TransportType.Description, Transport.SerialNumber
```

Why are there so many columns in the group by clause?

Comment: Except in MySQL & SQLite (which are lenient about the `GROUP BY` with sometimes indeterminate results), most RDBMS require every non-aggregated column (`MAX(),MIN(),SUM(),COUNT(),` etc) that appears in the `SELECT` list to be in the `GROUP BY`. If you learn aggregates in MySQL first, chances are you'll need to relearn to do them properly when moving to a different RDBMS.  Outside MySQL,SQLite, columns in the `SELECT` not also in `GROUP BY` will result in a query parse error.

Comment: What RDBMS are you used to working with, and what RBDMS did you see this query in context of?

Comment: Well, I'm actually leanring to use SQL Server Data tools.  I'm working my way through a self-help book, and this was one of the examples they used in the Query Designer.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski That would have been a great answer.

Comment: @GolezTrol I suppose so. I'll convert it into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except in MySQL & SQLite (which are lenient about the `GROUP BY` with sometimes indeterminate results), most RDBMS require every non-aggregated column (`MAX(),MIN(),SUM(),COUNT()`, etc) that appears in the `SELECT` list to be in the `GROUP BY`.

The behavior of MySQL & SQLite when columns from `SELECT` aren't listed in `GROUP BY` is not well defined. If for example, you execute a query like:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, COUNT(*) FROM names GROUP BY lastname
```

MySQL would give you a result without complaint.

However, if your table included two different values of `firstname` having the same `lastname`, your resultant `COUNT(*)` would count *both* of them while only returning the `firstname` of *one* of them. What's more, *which* `firstname` MySQL chooses to return isn't defined so you can't really rely on it returning the first of the pair, for example.

From a table like:

```
firstname, lastname
--------------------
Jane       Smith
John       Smith
Peter      Jones
```

The not-fully-correct result might be:

```
firstname, lastname, COUNT(*)
-----------------------------
Jane       Smith     2  <----wrong!
Peter      Jones     1
```

Outside MySQL & SQLite, columns referenced anywhere in the `SELECT` list not also appearing  in the `GROUP BY` will result in a query parse error.

Commonly here on Stack Overflow, we encounter users with questions about the `GROUP BY`, having just begun working with an RDBMS that is stricter about its usage. If you learn aggregates in MySQL first, chances are you'll need to relearn to do them properly when moving to a different RDBMS.

Comment: To complete the picture: according to the SQL standard, you are allowed to leave out non-aggregated columns from the `group by` clause if the non-grouped columns are functionally dependent on (at least) one group column: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY